# How to wrap the specific text with span tag inside the <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
var dtag = document.querySelector('p')
 
let len = dtag.innerHTML.split(' ').length


for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if(dtag.innerHTML.split(' ')[i] === 'Format'){
        
        let span = document.createElement('span')
span.append(dtag.innerHTML.split(' ')[i])
 dtag.append(span)
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="commanwords1.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

        <p>Printable Format hello shivam</p> 
    
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the HTML and In the script tag the javascript code.
Please let me know what should I have do to add the span tag in the specific word.

Comment: What is the result you want? This adds a span but its empty - you would not see any difference in the page.

Comment: `dtag.innerHTML.split(' ')[i]` is very expensive. You are doing the same operation over and over and over again

Comment: @topsail when I see the result it looks like
<body>
        <p>Printable Format hello shivam<span>Format</span></p> 
    </body>
But I need the output as below:
<p>Printable <span> Format </span> hello shivam </p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not working off the text nodes when you are trying to append the element. Since you are working with innerHTML you can build the string and replace the innerHTML.

```js
const dtag = document.querySelector('p')
const words = dtag.innerHTML.split(' ');
const mapped = words.map(word => word === 'Format' ? `<span>${word}</span>` : word);
dtag.innerHTML = mapped.join(' ');
```

```css
p span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<p>Printable Format hello shivam</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. so when I was doing dtag.innerHTML.split(' ')[i] why it is expensive? you mean if more number of words?

Comment: because you keep doing the same operation over and over again. If the split was on a string with thousands and thousands of words you would see a huge slowness. If you are going to loop over the all the words do the split once. `const words = dtag.innerHTML.split(' '); for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) { console.log(words[i]); }`